# How to create nested folders on home screen in Lollipop?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, home-screen-folders

Example:

- Assume that a folder F1 has ABC app icons (shortcuts) in it.
- Another folder F2 has XYZ app icons in it.
- The default launcher in COS12 doesn't allow inclusion of more than 16 icons in a single folder.
- Neither it provides the option to include one folder (F2) into another one (F1) so that the included folder (F2) would show up as a normal icon in F1 amongst other ABC icons, but when touched, would show its XYZ icons, hence achieving the proper nesting.

**How do I achieve this folder nesting in Lollipop?**

I've found that [Folder Organizer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abcOrganizer.lite) can do the job but it hasn't been ported to Lollipop's Material design. Result, your host folder looks in sync with rest of the UI (white background, smooth font) but the nested folder gives you a somewhat black background with not so smooth or crisp font. It also doesn't respect the current theme in place. Pretty much a *weird* combination in hand.

I believe [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)'s scenes can do this but I would like to have consistency between folders when it comes to their appearance.

---

I've a OnePlus One running rooted Cyanogen OS 12 with Xposed Framework installed.

Comment: This is relatively very close question: [Can I have a folder (on the home screen) with more than the default amount allowed per folder on the Nexus 5, which is 16?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/113435)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a [Scene](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/scenes.html) in [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm), loaded it using a task and created a shortcut using **Task Shortcut** widget to launch the scene.

- First image is showing a normal folder with some app shortcuts. See the folder icon titled "Nest". It is a task shortcut for the Scene.
- Second image is the Scene created in Tasker which is launched from a shortcut .

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

- To maintain consistency in appearance I took the background from [Material Palette](http://www.materialpalette.com/grey/blue-grey), cropped the color I wanted and loaded it into the Scene as background image.
- All the app icons are loaded using Image element in the Scene.
- Because it isn't a folder, so there is no drag and drop in it.

As for how to create this scene, you can see YoutTube videos or search [Tasker sub-reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Tasker) or the numerous websites filled with cool tutorials. You may consider my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/120405/96277) to get a rough idea of how to create a Scene in Tasker and how to use it then.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use a third-party launcher app. I had SlimROMS installed already and I noticed that its [SlimLauncher](https://plus.google.com/communities/104509876514579429216/stream/2f4fe780-9c2f-4535-bc56-217cf72647a1) doesn't [lag when Tasker is enabled](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/106660/home-launcher-in-cm12-lags-due-to-taskers-accessibility-feature). I grabbed it from that ROM and installed it on COS12. It feels like Trebuchet in terms of aesthetics, but much smoother and faster.

Anyhow, the point is, it doesn't restrict you to 16 icons per folder. You can have as many icons in your folder as much as you've in your app drawer.

[Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher) also allows you to add as many icons in a folder you want, so the need of nesting can be put on hold for a while.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge; First two images are for SlimLauncher and the last one is for Nova Launcher.)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]